# Understanding the virtual states referenced in multiphoton absorption studies

Tags: photons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, non-linear-optics, absorption

The Heisenberg energy-time uncertainty tells us that we can have so-called virtual states between eigenstates as long as the lifetime of these states is at most:

$\tau = (\frac{h}{4 \pi E_v})$

Where $h$ is the Planck constant ($6.62607 * 10^{-34} J*s$, or $4.135668 * 10^{-15} eV*s$), and $E_v$ is energy difference between our virtual state and the nearest eigenstate.  If we assume $E_v \approx 1 eV$ for a virtual state, we can estimate that this state can only exist for at most $\tau_2 \approx 3.29106 * 10^{-16}$ seconds.

Now, in the literature and wikipedia, I've repeatedly seen the claim that two-photon absorption (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_absorption) involves a single photon event promoting a molecule to a virtual state, and because the energy-time uncertainty allows this state to exist for some time $\tau$ (as estimated above for a $\approx 1 eV$ transition), if another photon strikes within this time window the energy of the two photons can be summed to allow for a transition with double the energy of a single photon.  For example, two $\lambda \approx 2.48 \mu m$ photons with energies of $\approx 0.5 eV$ each can, through a virtual state, sum to allow for a $\approx 1 eV$ transition correspond to the absorbance of a single $\lambda \approx 1.24 \mu m$ photon.

However, I'm having trouble understanding where the "memory" for the first photon absorbance is stored, since a virtual state is not a real eigenstate with distinct observables.  What mechanism allows for the energies of the two photons to be summed?  And are these energies being summed, or is there some energy loss associated with transitioning through a virtual state?  Please note that I fully understand there may not be an intuitive "memory mechanism", I just mean "memory" in the sense of being able to write down something like a descriptive state vector for a virtual state that accounts for the state's energy.

Finally, what does it mean to say that a virtual state can exist for "at most a time $\tau$" in the context of the energy-time uncertainty principle?  Is this just the expected lifetime for a state decaying exponentially with decay parameter $\lambda = \frac{1}{\tau}$?

---

A good soundbite for this question would be: how can we write down a quantum mechanical expression for a virtual state (say, in the context of raman spectroscopy) in Hilbert space?  And if it's ultimately correct to describe the virtual state using an interaction Hamiltonian between some particle's dipole and the EM field of an incoming photon (of some wavelength), how do we write down a description of this Hamiltonian in a rigorous manner?  Does this Hamiltonian give us any insight into the lifetime of the virtual state?

Also, why do I often see references to a Rigged Hilbert space when doing literature searches on this topic?  Take for example these two papers by Gadella, M.:

Gadella, M. A description of virtual scattering states in the rigged Hilbert space formulation of quantum mechanics. J. Math. Phys. 24, 2142 (1983).
https://doi.org/10.1063/1.525966

Gadella, M. Construction of rigged Hilbert spaces to describe resonances and virtual states. Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications 124(1–3), March 1984, 317 (1984).
https://doi.org/10.1016/0378-4371(84)90249-8

---

From (https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5620): Leon-Montiel, R. J. et. al. Role of the spectral shape of quantum correlations in two-photon virtual-state spectroscopy. (2013).

"The quantum mechanical calculation of the TPA [Two-Photon Absorption] transition probability shows that its value can be understood as a weighted sum of many energy non-conserving atomic transitions (virtual-state transitions) [22, 23] between energy levels."

Comment: Can you give a reference for some of the papers you speak of (especially the rigged Hilbert space)? Do you have Göppert‐Mayer's original paper? "Über Elementarakte mit zwei Quantensprüngen", Annalen der Physik vol 401 issue 3 1931? There is a translation also, both behind paywalls.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Thanks for your comment.  I updated my question with two papers by Gadella, M. that I was looking at - I've had trouble finding other relevant papers.  Also, here's Goppert-Mayer's original paper (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19314010303/pdf) for free, but I don't have a translation.

Comment: Fantastic! The original is enough! I shall have a look through the papers you cite: your question is an excellent one and I shall think about it some more. A trite answer is that the "memory" can be in a phenomenological model: we could add terms to the Hamiltonian of the form $\kappa(\nu_1,j_1,\nu_2,j_2)\, a_0^\dagger \,a(\nu_1,j_1)\, a(\nu_2,j_2) + H.c.$ where $a_0^\dagger$ raises the molecule state and $a(\nu,j)$ the annihilation operator for EM mode $j$ at frequency $\nu$ but I suspect this doesn't help much. You've likely already thought of the obvious that the "memory" could be ....

Comment: ... in the coupling of the molecule with the EM field and these are the lines I'll try thinking along.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I look forward to seeing what you can come up with!  I've been reading about the electric dipole approximation, and I did think of using a coupling Hamiltonian to describe the virtual state, but it's unclear to me how to proceed in a rigorous way w.r.t. the virtual state.

Comment: Yes, the Hamiltonian with terms like this will give a good working model, but one has no idea what co-efficients $\kappa(\nu_1,j_1,\nu_2,j_2)$ to put it: these would hopefully come out of a fuller analysis. In the meanwhile, if you're struggling with rigged Hilbert space, you might see http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43519/26076 and also the discussions http://mathoverflow.net/q/43313. The Wikipedia page is a bit light on: it glosses over the fact that the "smooth" functions $S$ have to be kitted with a stronger topology than in the Hilbert space so that the topology can "ferret out" ...

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance That MathOverflow link looks to be quite helpful...

Comment: ...distributions in $S^*$ (by "ferret out" I'm saying that the topology is strong enough to make things like the Dirac delta into a continuous functional, whereas it isn't continuous with respect to the Hilbert space norm). There's a great deal of detail that's glossed over and I'd suggest you should take a specific example $S$ = [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) and $S^*$ = [Tempered Distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) and keep this relatively simple (and, for QM most relevant) ....

Comment: ...example exclusively in mind - for QM you won't need anything else. So the set of bras is strictly bigger than the set of kets, so I'm guessing that the virtual states probably find an interpretation in $S^*\sim S$. So Todd Trimble is exactly right in his suspicions that the usual triple is $S\subset \mathbf{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^N)\subset S^*$ with $S$, $S^*$ the Scwhartz space and tempered distributions.

Comment: I also found (if you haven't already) the review article by [Roberts "Rigged Hilbert Space in Quantum Mechanics" here](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.cmp/1103839388)

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance This paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5620.pdf) seems to do a decent job at explaining the interaction Hamiltonian for two-photon absorption (see Section 2).  I'm reading through it now.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old like more than full seven years, but I would like to answer this question.

First, absorption occurs only when photons interact with matter or something. It does not have to do with memory as you said, and it has to do with the matter that the photon is interacting with, for example an electron bound to the matter. The wavefunction of a bounded electron (bounded by the attractive force of a nucleus or nuclei of an atom or a molecule) is deformed due to the interaction with the photon. The electron is interacting with the binding potential of the matter. If the intensity (i.e., flux) of the photon is not enough, then the wavefunction of the electron cannot escape enough from the center of the binding potential. On the other hand, if the intensity of the photon is enough, then
the electron can oscillating with the frequency component not allowed by the single photon frequency because of the binding potential. Mathematically, Fourier trasformation of the dipole acceleration of the matter has frequency component corresponding to the two photon. Therefore, the two photon absorption all has to do with the deformation of electron wavefunction in matter.

Regarding the Heisenberg uncertainty principle,

> The Heisenberg energy-time uncertainty tells us that we can have so-called virtual states between eigenstates as long as the lifetime of these states is at most:
>
> \tau=(\frac{h}{4πE_v})
>
> Where h is the Planck constant (6.62607∗10−34J∗s, or 4.135668∗10−15eV∗s), and Ev is energy difference between our virtual state and the nearest eigenstate. If we assume Ev≈1eV for a virtual state, we can estimate that this state can only exist for at most τ2≈3.29106∗10−16 seconds.

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle is overused or misused here and there maybe due to its popularity and concise but powerful meaning in physics. It does not have to do with Heisenberg uncertainty principle.