# Superposition of discrete level and continuum: Electron bound and free

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition

Superposition between discrete states of a system is widely considered in the literature, but this system, e.g., a $H$ atom, can also have a continuum in its energy spectrum.

Can the state of a system be in a superposition of an energy level in the discrete part of the spectrum with one level in the continuum part (or with an interval thereof)?

In other words: Can an electron in a $H$ atom be in a superposition of bound to and free from the proton?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Is it possible that we have a physical state which is a mixture of discrete eigenstates and continuous ones?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139311/