# What happens to the configuration manifold when one quantizes the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

A system in classical mechanics can be described by a configuration manifold $Q$ and a Lagrangian 
\begin{equation}
L:TQ\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
where $TQ$ is the tangent bundle or a Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
L:{ T }^{ * }Q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
where ${ T }^{ * }Q$ is the cotangent bundle.

If one now quantizes the Hamiltonian by "replacing the variables with operators"
\begin{equation}
H=T+V\quad \rightarrow \quad \hat { H } =\hat { T } +\hat { V } 
\end{equation}
what exactly happens with the configuration manifold $Q$? Which dimension has $Q$ after the quantization and what *is* a point $a \in Q$ when we choose local coordinates.

---

My guess is that a point $({ q }_{ 1 },...,{ q }_{ n },{ p }_{ 1 },...,{ p }_{ n })$ transforms in the following way:
\begin{equation}
{ q }_{ i }\quad \rightarrow \quad \left| { x }_{ i } \right> =\delta({ x }_{ i }-x) \quad \quad \quad \quad { p }_{ i }\quad \rightarrow \quad { -i\hbar\partial }_{ { x }_{ i } }
\end{equation}

But then the position/momentum-coordinates become distributions respectively differential operators and I don't think that such a mathematical set has the structure of a manifold.

Comment: I believe you are confusing two *theories* with the *most popular description pictures* utilized for them. QM has a perfectly fine [description in phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) , as well, and, conversely, classical mechanics in Hilbert space, as well; and contrasting the structure of the two descriptions does not fully contrast the two theories.

Comment: By the way, the nitpicking definition in Dirac's book is $q_i\to |q_i\rangle= \delta (\hat x -q_i) \rangle$, where $\rangle$ is Dirac's "standard ket", the translationally invariant vacuum, i.e. the $p\to 0$ limit of $|p\rangle$.

Comment: [State space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_(physics)) is what you just might be after; also [see](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241710/the-state-space-is-somehow-defined-by-the-observables).

Comment: If you are fearless of mathematical notation, your best bet is *Foundations of Quantum Theory: From Classical Concepts to Operator Algebras* by Klaas Landsman, Springer 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "configuration manifold" in quantum mechanics. "Quantization" does not map points in the classical configuration manifold to anything in the quantum theory. Quantization produces a quantum theory from a classical theory, it is not a map that turns classical states into quantum states.

"Quantization" is, in general, not a well-defined process, see e.g. [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/323946/50583). There are several heuristic quantization procedures of varying sophistication, such as [canonical quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization) and [geometric quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization), but none of these preserve the classical setup of a *configuration manifold* - quantum states are rays in a Hibert space or points in a projective Hilbert space or quasi-probability distributions on (classical Hamiltonian) phase space, but there is never a map from classical to quantum states. In naive canonical quantization the quantum space of states is the space of *wavefunctions* on the classical configuration space, but that doesn't mean that individual points in the configuration space would be mapped to specific wave functions - that's simply not what quantization is supposed to do.